# How to debug which script is throwing Cannot read property \"length\" from null (NLRecordScripting.scriptInit$lib#799)

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, netsuite-rest-api

I am getting this error while updating employee in record netsuite. I am not sure what is causing this error.
How can I find out which script or what is causing this?

I have check in script logs (`Customization > Scripting > Script execution logs`) but nothing shows up there.

I have also tried to disable all scripts associated with employee record but this error is still being thrown.

Fetching the employee record is working all fine.
It's not only happening for one record but each record for the employee.
And employee update is working in UI all fine.

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot of the log message?